# Generating unique cache key with Spring KeyGenerator not working

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache

I'm having the issue when my cache keys are colliding in Spring using the `@Cacheable` annotation. For instance, with the following two methods:

```
@Cacheable("doOneThing")
public void doOneThing(String name) {
  // do something with name
}

@Cacheable("doAnotherThing")
public void doAnotherThing(String name) {
  // do some other thing with name
}
```

Here is my cache configuration, in which I've added a `keyGenerator` and a `cacheManager` bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

  @Bean
  public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
  }

  @Bean
  public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
    RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    return redisTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    return new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
  }

  @Bean
  public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
    return new KeyGenerator() {
      @Override
      public Object generate(Object o, Method method, Object... params) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(o.getClass().getName());
        sb.append(method.getName());
        for (Object param : params) {
          sb.append(param.toString());
        }
        return sb.toString();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

For some reason, the cache key always gets set to the `name` parameter in the method, not the result of the `keyGenerator.generate(..)` method, causing both methods to return the same cache result.

I know that I can specify the key manually on each `@Cacheable` annotation, but that seems a little extensive for every method I'd like to cache.

### Edit

I've noticed that setting the `keyGenerator` option inside of the `@Cacheable` annotation to the name of my bean resolves the issue, like so:

```
@Cacheable(value = "doOneThing", keyGenerator = "keyGenerator")
public void doOneThing(String name) {
  // do something with name
}
```

And setting the `keyGenerator` option in the `@CacheConfig` annotation on the class also resolves the issue. It seems that this shouldn't be necessary though. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you pass a single argument to the `@Cacheable` annotation it is interpreted as the name of the cache to use.  Did you _really_ want to be using two different caches?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your configuration should implement [`CachingConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachingConfigurer.html) (usually you would extend from `CachingConfigurerSupport`) to customize how caching works.

Comment: Thank you! Extending `CachingConfigurerSupport` in my `CacheConfig` class resolved the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. It made me realize that we should probably be a bit more explicit about it. I'll see what I can do to update the documentation in that area. Thanks for raising this!

Comment: StephaneNicoll
May i ask you why overriding the method after extending CachingConfigurer is not enough to let the system know what instances of CacheManager and KeyGenerator it has to use and instead we need to annotate the methods returning them with @Bean ?

Comment: Please create your own question