# Spring KeyGenerator For Appending Cache name to the key

Tags: spring, caching, redis

I am using spring cache with Redis for caching

I have the following methods:

```
    @CachePut(value ="DATA1", key = "#key1")
    public Object saveData1(long key1, Object obj) {
        return obj;
    }


    @CachePut(value ="DATA2", key = "#key1")
    public Object saveData2(long key1, Object obj) {
        return obj;
    }
```

This is causing collisions in keys and the data is being overridden.

I want to generate the key with the cache name appended to it.

Like: DATA1-key1, DATA2-key1.

Is it possible?

I have seen a few examples which use class name and method name. But I want to use the cache name.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating unique cache key with Spring KeyGenerator not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574786/generating-unique-cache-key-with-spring-keygenerator-not-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom key generator like this:

```
@Component("myKeyGenerator")
public class MyKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        String[] value = new String[1];
        long key;
        CachePut cachePut = method.getAnnotation(CachePut.class);
        if (cachePut != null) {
            value = cachePut.value();
        }
        key = (long) params[0];
        return value[0] + "-" + key;
    }
}
```

And use it like below:

```
@CachePut(value = "DATA1", keyGenerator = "myKeyGenerator")
```

I haven't test this but should work, atleast you will get a basic idea how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know we could get the annotation of the method.

Comment: @CachePut(value ="DATA1", key = "'DATA1-' + #key1") should work

Answer (score 1):

You need to set parameter "usePrefix" as true in your CacheManager bean. This will prepend cacheName in your keys.

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager">
    ...
     <property name="usePrefix"><value>true</value></property>
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: This is in the redis docs:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/1.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.html